# Angular change notification on subproperty

Tags: angular, angular5, two-way-binding

I've got a child component in my Angular 5 application that does two-way binding, and the binding is working properly.  I'm having a bit of an issue with knowing about the change though in the parent controller.  In the parent I use the child component like so:

```
<app-lab-hazard-classification-question-group
        primaryQuestion="Does the lab contain mechanical tools?"
        [(primaryValue)]="lab.hazardClassificationDetails.mechanicalExists"></app-lab-hazard-classification-question-group>
```

The `lab` variable is an `@Input()` to the parent control.  When I evaluate the value of `lab.hazardClassificationDetails.mechanicalExists` it's properly being set by the child component.  I need to know though, in the parent control, when that value gets modified.  Because the `lab` variable itself doesn't change, the `ngOnChanges` method isn't actually called.

Do I have to add a `(change)` item to the child controller and explicitly bind that to be notified of the change?  I was hoping for a more generic way as I have around 10 of these child elements, and I don't care "what" value it changed to, just that it did in fact change.

The child component's .ts file has this:

```js
@Input() primaryValue: boolean;
@Output() primaryValueChange = new EventEmitter();

onPrimaryChanged(): void {
    this.primaryValueChange.emit(this.primaryValue);
}
```

and the HTML has something like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="primary" name="primary" required
        [(ngModel)]="primaryValue"
        (change)="onPrimaryChanged()">
            <option [ngValue]="null || undefined">-- Select --</option>
            <option [ngValue]="true">Yes</option>
            <option [ngValue]="false">No</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Could you please create a stackblitz? It would be great to play with this example a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach could be to emit an event with `EventEmitter` from the child component to the parent component in case of value change.

Comment: So you're saying to add the `(change)` item to each of the items in the parent's HTML?

Comment: @Balázs Takács you meant ``EventEmitter``? I think this idea is good, create custom event with ``@Output`` and inform parent whenever some value changes.

Comment: @Buczkowski Thank you for the catch. I meant EventEmitter.

Comment: @Gargoyle You mentioned that you do not care what is the new value after the change. By creating an EventEmitter you do not have to pass the new value to the parent component. It is enough to just notify it with a simple emit.

Comment: I do have emitters for each child question that passes the value to support the two-way binding. I just added an extra `change` emitter that they all call as well so I added a `(change)="onSomethingChanged()"` to each of the HTML blocks.